# Remote desktop connected with Remmina is very slow

Tags: remote-access, ubuntu-20.04

Connected Ubuntu 20.04 machine to remote Ubuntu 20.04 machine using remmina tool.

But it is very slow , can you please suggest me any tips.

Comment: First suggestion is to ask this in the correct place. Either https://SuperUser.com or https://ServerFault.com. And when you do, include more details like network details, latency etc.